# gem install rails on git bash (for Windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

gem install rails
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
```

C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0 -r ./siteconf20220326-12676-skaw7l.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
make DESTDIR= clean

current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
make DESTDIR=
generating websocket_mask-x64-mingw-ucrt.def
compiling websocket_mask.c
make: gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:246: websocket_mask.o] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/websocket-driver-0.7.5/gem_make.out
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...

Please help me to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

have you followed any Youtube tutorials if yes, then yeah you are not alone I have also screwed up and don't have any solutions yet but I think reinstalling from the beginning from your own not from the tutorials, you may succeed.
If I succeed then I would tell ya!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks.. I had installed it successfully in command prompt